# CSS how to make an effect of a hand holding cards

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-transforms

So basically i want to have an transparent image of a hand holding cards, then i want to display cards on a curve like when you are holding 10 cards in your hand (not fixed 10 of course). So they should be positioned on a curved dome.
I'm working in angular, and i know that i have to accomplish this via position absolute and transform: translate-rotate css, just don't know how

I'm also working with bootstrap so this image with cards should be in a col-12 and compatible on a smaller screens.

I only have the parts of the code that i took from a guy that positioned elements in a circle - [Bootstrap 3 align elements into circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081094/bootstrap-3-align-elements-into-circle)
i tried to play around with translate and rotate but couldn't get it working

[image]

Comment: Do you have anything that you've tried that you can share?  If for nothing else than to serve as a jumping off point or [mcve] for community members who might wish to help you?

Comment: @AlexanderNied i only have the parts of the code that i took from a guy that positioned elements in a circle - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081094/bootstrap-3-align-elements-into-circle
 here's the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/k7yxtpc7/ i tried to play around with translate and rotate but couldn't get it working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the way I approached it. There's alot going on here, but it's basically

- setting a overall width to work with
- using a predefined number of cards and overall angle allowance
- using math to distribute and angle the cards
- using `transform-origin: bottom center;`  to give the effect

```js
let cards = document.querySelector('.cards');
let w = cards.offsetWidth;
let totalarc = 270;
let numcards = 7;
let angles = Array(numcards).fill('').map((a, i) => (totalarc / numcards * (i + 1)) - (totalarc/2 + (totalarc / numcards) / 2));
let margins = angles.map((a, i) => w / numcards * (i + 1));

angles.forEach((a, i) => {
  let s = `transform:rotate(${angles[i]}deg);margin-left:${margins[i]}px;`
  let c = `<div class='card' style='${s}'></div>`;
  cards.innerHTML += c;
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cards {
  width: 150px;
}

.card {
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #999;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .5;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='cards'></div>
  <div class='hand'>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works great! One more question, how would you now center this .container inside a bootstrap's .col-12 div? And make it responsive on smaller screens? I guess making image width height in % instead of pixels would solve one part of it

Comment: I managed to get the first part by setting width of the container to 20% and then margin: 0 auto. The content is then centered

Comment: Not sure on the other question. Yes you could probably set percentages for the card sizes or you might want to just set up breakpoints that correspond with bootstraps grid and then use classes to manage the card size. That way you'll have a little more control